# How to plot this?

Tags: matlab, function, plot, equation

So I'm given this equation `x + e^(x^2) + e^(y^2) = r` and I would like to plot it for `r = [1.5, 4]`. 
My work:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-1.5:0.1:1.5,-1.5:0.1:1.5);
Z = X + exp(X^2) + exp(Y^2);
hold on;
[C,h]=contour(X,Y,Z,1.5:0.1:4);
clabel(C,h)
hold off;
```

but I only get straight lines, no circles. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the `.` in `.^` for element-wise power operation. Replace the second row with the following, and the contour plot will yield the sought-after level curves

```
Z = X + exp(X.^2) + exp(Y.^2);
```

Comment: @den We've all (well, at least some of us, I presume) been there :) Happy to help.